# Internet Explorer 8 issue with Select2 JQuery plugin

Tags: internet-explorer-8, jquery-select2

I have tested Select2 in IE8 (amongst many others) and it works great.

I have a user who claims their IE 8 version number is IE 8.0.7601.175.14 and Select2 does not work very well with it. Select2 random deletes characters as you type, and the dropdown won't actually dropdown

Just about the only place I can find a reference to this IE8 version number is [here](http://translate.google.co.uk/translate?hl=en&sl=de&u=http://www.motor-talk.de/forum/ausloggen-geht-nicht-t4079891.html&prev=/search?q=8.0.7601.175.14&hl=en&sa=X&ei=WgBcUcK_FYq-PKP3gKAM&ved=0CDkQ7gEwAA)

This [MS article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969393) goes up to only the 7600 range

The [IE8 Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_8) has a number of version numbers, none of which this is.

Any ideas how I can fix this? or at least figure out what IE8 version this is and try to test against it?

Comment: I think the user wanted to report version 8.0.7601.17514 (without a dot between 175 and 14

Comment: maybe, do you have a link to somewhere that mentions that number?

Comment: I see my IE8 version that is  8.0.7601.17514 and google-ing it you'll see more results